# Allow events to be dragged only onto background events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-4

I am managing appointments on `fullcalendar`. I have available slots of time where I can create new appointments. Also I can drag appointments onto available time slots which are shown as **background events**.

I only want the drop functionality on background event slots.

I have tried the `eventOverlap` method but it only works when the event is dropped on a background event. If the event is dropped elsewhere then I am unable to detect whether I am dropping the event on background event or on empty slot.

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    // height: 1080,
    plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'interaction'],
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },

    events: {
        url: getUrl(),
        failure: function() {
            toastr.error('Unable to load calendar data, Please try later');
        },
        success: function() {

        }
    },


    loading: function(bool) {

    },
    defaultDate: Date.now(),

    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    eventClick: function(info) {

        if (info.event.extendedProps.type == 'Calendar') {
            showCreateModal(info.event);
        }
        if (info.event.extendedProps.type == "Appointment") {
            showUpdateModal(info.event);
        }
    },

    eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
        return stillEvent.extendedProps != '' && stillEvent.extendedProps.type === 'Calendar' ? true : false;
    },

    eventDrop: function(info) {
        // check if event is being dropped on past date / slot
        if (moment(info.event.start) < moment()) {
            info.revert();
            return;
        }

        // check if event is being dropped on future slot
        if (moment(info.event.start) > moment()) {
            swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "You are about to re-schedule this appointment!",
                    icon: "warning",
                    // buttons: true,
                    buttons: ["No", "Yes !"],
                    dangerMode: true,
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        submitForm(false, true, info.event);
                    } else {
                        info.revert();
                    }
                });
        }

    }

});

calendar.render();
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that `eventOverlap` doesn't help you here, because it's only triggered when the event is dropped onto a background event. It doesn't help you when the event is dropped somewhere else.

In fullCalendar 4 you can achieve what you need via the [eventConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventConstraint) setting. This allows you to limit event dragging to specific windows of time. As the documentation says, you can provide a `groupId` value to this setting, and then

> ...events that are being dragged or resized must be fully contained by at least one of the events linked to by the given `groupId`.

All you need to do as well as that is give all your background events the same groupId.

For example, if you set:

```
eventConstraint: 1
```

and then have entries such as these within your event data:

```
  {
    start: "2019-07-10 09:00",
    end: "2019-07-10 12:00",
    rendering: "background",
    groupId: 1
  },
  {
    start: "2019-07-11 09:00",
    end: "2019-07-11 12:00",
    rendering: "background",
    groupId: 1
  },
```

This would mean that you would only be allowed to drag or resize an existing calendar event if you drag/resize it so that it falls entirely within the time periods covered by those background events which have a groupId of 1.

Here's a working demonstration: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jjdEjB

Comment: i have solved this issue by eventConstraint also for updating values in database i have added some additional check in php to chehck if i am dropping event on correct date