# fullcalendar business hours with validity period

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I would like my calendar to only allow the user to create new events during business hours. The catch is that the business hours are not the same each week, they depend on the date.
My table with the business hours looks like this:

```
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| day | startTime | endTime  | firstDate  | lastDate   |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|   6 | 08:00:00  | 12:30:00 | 2021-12-20 | NULL       |
|   6 | 13:00:00  | 16:30:00 | 2021-12-20 | NULL       |
|   2 | 08:00:00  | 17:00:00 | 2021-12-27 | 2021-12-27 |
|   4 | 08:00:00  | 17:00:00 | 2021-12-29 | 2021-12-29 |
+-----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

The business hours in FullCalendar don't have an option to specify validity periods.

I have been looking at using background events but don't quite understand how to achieve the desired result that way.

How can I limit new events to specific times for each day of the week where these times vary each week?

Comment: Background events is the next-best approach. Where exactly are you stuck with that?

Comment: Background events only have a start and an end date and time. So it seems that I would have to write code to generate a separate background event for each and every day in the calendar that it applies to.
Is there a better way?

Also I have to figure out how to only allow new events on top of these background events and not anywhere else.

Comment: `it seems that I would have to write code to generate a separate background event for each and every day in the calendar that it applies to`...yes, although you could use fullCalendar's recurring event functionality to make that less painful, potentially. Or if the business hours change according to a predictable schedule, you could have a script which generates events for a given date range, according to some pre-defined rules. Obviously I don't know anything about what the real-life scenario is here.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap can help you with making sure events are only created over the top of the background events - see the example at that link.

Comment: Thank you but unless I misunderstand that link using selectOverlap for this would require creating events that cover everything but the background events.Am I missing something?

Comment: I knew I'd done something like this before - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959578/allow-events-to-be-dragged-only-onto-background-events . Same principle for you, except you'll use `selectConstraint` instead of `eventConstraint`. Sorry, selectOverlap was a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

This gets us recurring background events:

```
{
    startTime: '08:00:00',
    endTime: '12:30:00',
    daysOfWeek: '6',
    startRecur: '2021-12-20',
    rendering: 'background',
    groupId: 1
},
{
    startTime: '13:00:00',
    endTime: '16:30:00',
    daysOfWeek: '6',
    startRecur: '2021-12-20',
    rendering: 'background',
    groupId: 1
}
```

For more information on recurring events see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events